# How can I append a new element to XMLDOM in VBA?

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am reading a xmlDoc that has 2 elements in ad_model.

```
Set ad_model = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//AD_MODEL")
Cells(1, "B") = ad_model(0).Text
Cells(2, "B") = ad_model(1).Text
```

I want to add a new element ("TESTE") in xmlDoc. How can I make it?
I tried:

A) `ad_model(3).Text = "TESTE"`

B)    `Set teste = xmlDoc.createElement("AD_MODEL")
    teste.Text = "TESTE"`

C) `ad_model.append("TESTE")`

What can I do?

Comment: http://www.functionx.com/vbaccess/Lesson63.htm   You need to work with the underlying XML document if you want to add new elements.

Comment: Please show original XML and desired result for a [mcve].

Comment: If by "XMLDOM", you mean that you have created a `Microsoft.XMLDOM` object then don't do that. The correct type to create is `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0` - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/xmlteam/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer) for an explanation